# How did OpenLayers 3 managed to export map from other domain?

Tags: openlayers-2, html5

As far as I know, you cannot use canvas.toDataURL() on a tainted canvas (i.e. cross-origin). Looking at this [example](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/export-map.html) it seems the tiles are coming from different origin (tile.openstreetmap.org). How did OL3 managed to use toDataURL() in this case?

I tried monitoring network traffic and it seems no proxy are being used to circumvent cross-origin rules.

Comment: exports from the users cache on their web browser.

Comment: @Mapperz, can you elaborate how is this done?

Answer (score 7):

TLDR; Add crossOrigin: 'anonymous' to your source params.

---

This took awhile for me to dig down to but I think I have the answer. Assuming your tile server is not in your domain, and that it is providing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* response header as mine was.

The key is the OSM source they use. If you take a look at the documentation for [ol.source.OSM](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.OSM.html) you can see that there is a crossOrigin option (which defaults to 'anonymous' for osm)

This got me looking into the source for the tile source, I am using WMTS primarily but it didn't seem like these were defaulting to 'anonymous' instead requiring the dev to set this in the options for the given source.

Adding crossOrigin: 'anonymous' to my source options fixed this problem for me.

```
var source = new ol.layer.Tile({    
  ...
  source: new ol.source.WMTS({
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    ...
```

Adding this parameter changed my request headers to include one parameter:

```
 Origin: http://localhost:3001
```

Which as far as I can tell allows it to pass the [CORS resource sharing test](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-sharing-check-0). Just not sure if this is due to 3 now being able to be checked, or more probably that it sets the omit credentials flag in the ajax request thus passing step 2.

Comment: You rule, man...

Answer (score 1):

So I guess the answer to this question is on the manner the other domain is responding to the request. Upon closer inspection of the reply of OSM server (e.g. http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/6/56/29.png), the header is set to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` thus there are no cross-origin issue encountered.

Comment: There has to be more to it. All my server responses (map tiles and static files) have this header set, but the canvas is still tainted.

Answer (score -1):

They are able to serve the tiles from a different domain with the help of a proxy.cgi script which must be present in the ol3js.org web server.

To understand how to workaround the Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem, please, read the section `Configuring an OpenLayers proxy.cgi for Loading Local and Remotely Hosted GeoServer WFS Data` **[here](http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html)**. That principle applies to all map servers, not only for GeoServer.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. If you view the application's network traffic you will see the tiles being sourced from a different domain by the browser. No proxy is being used.

Comment: It's a tested issue. I've installed a few GeoServers using only this method and I don't have any problems.

Comment: I mean in this case you are incorrect. I'm well aware that the proxy approach works, but the referenced application doesn't use it.

Comment: No, I think you are missing one point from the top question and from the article mentioned by me. When you have your own domain with a web server installed, your own web server rejects all requests to serve pages/code from another domain. That's all. It isn't my intention to describe in a comment what it's explained clear in that article. Don't make a confusion with a mapserver accessed with the localhost or an ip address.

Comment: @ tomfumb And no, I'm not incorrect.

Comment: you're still describing something that is irrelevant in this question. The site referenced in the question *does not* use a proxy.cgi script. If you don't believe me please see: http://i.imgur.com/gFMrczn.png If a proxy was used the tiles would come from something like ol3js.org/proxy.cgi, but they don't - they come from an entirely separate domain. The question's poster sees this and understands this means the canvas *is* indeed tainted. Your answer and comments are relevant to different questions but not this one. One may therefore choose to describe the answer as 'incorrect'

Comment: I've been using proxy in solving cross-origin problems. My initial thoughts on how the export was achieved in the example was somehow through a proxy. But as what @tomfumb has done, I monitored network traffic and it seems no proxy request are being made.

I'm really interested on the details about Mapperz comment that the export was achieved using cached data/images.

Answer (score -1):

This works with any kind of source

```
var source = new ol.layer.Tile({    
  ...
  source: new ol.source.WMTS({
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    ...
```